# Can't install pynput package on pydroid3

Tags: python

when I try to install pynput on pydroid3 on android it says this

**/storage/emulated/0 $ pip install pynput
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x70a5137690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname')': /simple/pynput/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x70a4d9bfd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname')': /simple/pynput/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x70a4dac610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname')': /simple/pynput/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x70a4dad3d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname')': /simple/pynput/**

actually in every package installation it says same like this.
How can I solve this I hava installed pydroid repository plugin also